# I wrote the following code in matlab to randomize and after that round numbers 3 to 8 in 3x4 matrix but i want to not be repeated numbers in rows

Tags: matlab

i wrote this code for randomize and round numbers

```
x=3+5*rand(3,4);
for n=1:3
for m=1:4
  y(n,m)=round(x(n,m));

   
end
end
y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `randperm()` function may be an option. The first argument of `randperm()` sets the range. In this case `randperm(6,4)` will generate 4 numbers that are within the range 1 to 6 (a random permuatation of integers in this case permutations of 6). If we add 2 to this result we can generate an array of length 4 that will have values ranging from 3 to 8. Here we can use one for-loop and generate the rows upon each iteration.

[image: Randomly Generated Array]

```
Array = zeros(3,4);

for Row = 1: 3
Array(Row,:) = randperm(6,4) + 2;
end

Array
```

Comment: thank you it is what i look for it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `rand()` function returns numbers between 0 and 1, so it probably doesn't make sense to use this function and then round the numbers off. If you're looking for random integers use `randi()` instead.

With this in mind, the following code produces a 3 by 4 matrix filled with random integers and no repeats:

```
maxInteger = 12; %change to any number greater than 3x4 = 12

y = randi(maxInteger, 3, 4);

used = [];
for i = 1:numel(y)
    while sum(find(used == y(i)))>0
        y(i) = randi(maxInteger);
    end
    used = [used, y(i)];
end
```

If the while loop takes too long (as might happen with large matrices) consider filling a matrix by pulling and removing elements from a predecided list of integers.

Comment: firstly thanks for your answer but i dont understand where can i use this code forgive me for that i am beginner in matlab.Should i keep my code when i write your code?

Comment: @Scott Nice implementation and thought process, clever.

Comment: Ozoz, You can run this code on its own. I'm not sure it does exactly what you're looking for but it should get you started.
@MichaelTr7 Thanks!